# very strange problem: nothing happens after submitting in aspx webpage

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, submit

tested on: windows server 2008 with visual studio 2010 and windows vista with visual studio 2008.

following unusuall problem has appeared.

i have a usercontrol and website where control will be showed.
if im checking radio buttons of control and clicking on submit which is also in ctrol inside there happens nothing. no request to server, just silence.

everything looks fine and standard but i cant find a problem. please help, because its annoying!

usercontrol.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EmployeeCategorizationControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="EmployeeCategorizationControl.EmployeeCategorizationControl" %>

<div id="categorizationOfEmployee">
<div>Categorization od Employee</div><br />
    <div id="firstCategory">
        <div style="float: left; width: 250px;">
            Is not a permanent employee</div>
        <div>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="YesNoIsNotPermanentEmployee" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondCategory">
        <div style="float: left; width: 250px;">
            Is a fixed-term employee</div>
        <div>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="YesNoIsFixedTermEmployee" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="thirdCategory">
        <div style="float: left;  width: 250px;">
            No external recruit</div>
        <div>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="YesNoExternalRecruit" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="btCreate" style="margin-left: 200px; margin-top: 10px;">
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Create Checklist" ID="btCreateChecklist" />
    </div>
</div>
```

usercontrol.ascx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btCreateChecklist.Click += new EventHandler(btCreateChecklist_Click);

        }

void btCreateChecklist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValueOfIsNotPermanentEmployee = YesNoIsNotPermanentEmployee.Text;
            ValueOfIsFixedTermEmployee = YesNoIsFixedTermEmployee.Text;
            ValueOfNoExternalRecruit = YesNoExternalRecruit.Text;
            UserCategoryID = ValueOfIsNotPermanentEmployee + ValueOfIsFixedTermEmployee + ValueOfNoExternalRecruit;
        }
```

default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="EmployeeCategorizationControl._Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UserControl" TagName="EmployeeCategorizationControl" Src="~/EmployeeCategorizationControl.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <UserControl:EmployeeCategorizationControl runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem (VS2008, .NET3.5 , ASP.NET Development Server). Is this the only page / usercontrol that fails to postback?

Comment: Can you try this :
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Create Checklist" ID="btCreateChecklist" OnClick="btCreateChecklist_Click" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code appears to work perfectly as I see it. I've transplanted your code into a local application as is (changing namespaces to eliminate compile errors) and it posts back just fine. However, your event doesn't do anything except set a couple of variables (which you don't explain what they do or relate to). Are you sure it's not performing the post back? This page is small enough that a postback may not even cause the screen to flash (since there is no actual action going on). You should put some visible action into the event method such as changing the text of a label or the `BackColor` of the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `AutoEventWireup="true"` there is no need for:

```
btCreateChecklist.Click += new EventHandler(btCreateChecklist_Click);
```

Either set it to `false` or remove the above statement.

Comment: i have it in default.aspx as in control.ascx

Comment: Read up on how it works. It hooks up the events given their names, automatically.

Comment: `AutoEventWireup` only applies to page events. btCreateChecklist.Click is not a page event. It also would not be responsible for this behavior. If this was the problem, his code would generate 2 click events.